# Помогите превратить двумерный массив в одномерный с++

Tags: c++

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j, n, m, k = 0, p, max;
    cout << "write n:";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "write m:";
    cin >> m;

    int A[n][m];
    int mas[n*m];

    cout << "Input matrix A \n";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for ( j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cout << "A" << "[" << i << "]" << "[" << j << "]" << "=";
            cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << "matrix A \n";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << A[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << endl;    
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for ( j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            A[n][m] = mas[n*m];
        }
    }

    cout << "\n masyv: ";
    for ( i = 0; i < n*m; i++) {
        // A[i][j] = mas[i];
        cout << mas << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Сразу в глаза бросается раз: `A[n][m]=mas[n*m];` два: `cout<<mas<<" ";`

Comment: #include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i,j,n,m,k=0,p,max;
cout<<"write n:";
cin>>n;
cout<<"write m:";
cin>>m;
int A[n][m];
int mas[n*m];
cout<<"Input matrix A \n";
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
for (j=0; j<m; j++){
    cout<<"A"<<"["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"]"<<"=";
cin>>A[i][j];
}
}
cout<<"matrix A \n";
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
for (j=0; j<m; j++)
cout<<A[i][j]<<"\t";
cout<<endl;

}
cout << "\n masyv: ";
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
for (j=0; j<m; j++){

//A[i][j]=mas[i];
 mas[i*j]=A[i][j];
  cout<<mas[i*j]<<" ";
}
}
}

Comment: `int n,m;...;int A[n][m];` - в С++ такое не допускается. Определитесь с языком сначала.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    srand((time(0)));

    int n, m;
    int *a;
    int **arr;

    cout << "write n:";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "write m:";
    cin >> m;

    //определим размер и сам одномерный массив
    int sizeA = n * m;
    arr = new int*[n];

    //определим двумерный массив
    a = new int[n*m];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[m];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            //или cin >> arr[i][j]
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }


    int Ai = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++, Ai++) {
            a[Ai] = arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " " << endl;
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        delete []arr[i];
    }
    delete []arr;

    delete []a;

    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```